# What are the anomalies in this picture of earth?

Tags: image-processing, image-compression, extraterrestrial-cameras

I was playing around with the New NASA pic of earth (posted July 20th 2015 on Nasa Goddard space flight center on Flickr). I've found this very odd structure on the bottom right corner that is pretty much hidden in the darkness. There must be some kind of un-spectacular reason for this to look like a barber's pole, henceforth, this image will be named "Nasa's barber pole" until proven through some ultra-complicated computer mathematics.

[image]

I'm asking photographers because I would like a point of view from people who work with images either through Photoshop or whatever, Are these type of anomalies normal? Has anyone else noticed these things?

Comment: Do you have the link to the original?

Comment: https://flic.kr/p/vj7kj2, it alsom mentions nothing about JPEG compression or any JPEG for that matter. this is the original pics "EXIF"-JFIFVersion - 1.01
X-Resolution - 72 dpi
Y-Resolution - 72 dpi
Orientation - Horizontal (normal)
Color Space - sRGB

Comment: "JFIF" is a standard format for JPEG files. Details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format).

Comment: Ok, so JFIF is related to JPEG. Why do we get mediocre quality then, this is NASA we are talking about. And we are talking about an image of earth, last image of earth (The blue marble) is from 1972, so yup, I would like some real quality images.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your expectations, here. Or why you're looking on Flickr, for that matter. Get the original 1977 blue marble image from http://visibleearth.nasa.gov/view.php?id=55418 - also JPEG, but these artifacts aren't visible. Or an updated composite image from 1997, available in TIFF formta: http://visibleearth.nasa.gov/view.php?id=54388

Comment: I guess I don't have any expectations, I've just never seen a JPEG anomaly with such depth, shading and size, that's all. Thank you for Pic links, very awesome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking at JPEG artifacts. The JPEG compression scheme divides an image up into 8x8 pixel blocks and rebuilds each block using a collection of 2D waves as building blocks:

[image]

You can faithfully recreate any image by adding together a combination of wave images with the correct brightnesses. However JPEG is a lossy compression algorithm and so it throws away some waves to reduce size. Thus JPEG artifacts often resemble the more primitive waves as the higher order more complicated waves have been dropped. This can appear give structure to what might just be random noise in the original image.

Here is an extremely highly compressed image:

[image]

Most 8x8 blocks feature only the most primitive wave, the one in the top left corner of the first image. However in the background and around the "JPG" text you can see a few of the more detailed waves being used.

Your "barbers pole" is probably nothing more than a collection of dim stars in the background that has taken on a more structured, detailed looking appearance due to certain wave shapes being used that make it appear stripy with a ball on the top!

Either that, or it's aliens who can camouflage their ships to look exactly like JPEG artifacts in order to escape detection...

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2aEzeMDHMA

Comment: So even a "billion-dollar" funded NASA will release images with botched JPEG artifacts in their official pics and offer no explanation? If they are gonna remove the stars (that are unvisible of course...) why not just black out the rest instead of risking these JPEG artifacts. Do they use "Windows Paint" over there 'o wha?

Comment: Why do you think the stars are removed? Dynamic range is dynamic range, even in space!

Comment: Ok then, so they removed the stars, and left all this weird stuff floating around in the shadows? Again, they never mention JPEG, the original pic is a 'composite (of course)' of all kinds of mega-advanced sattelites, infrared, gamma ray, etc, cameras. But let's botch all that research by compressing into JPEG? huh*?

Comment: @NormLDude they posted it on Flickr which obviously isn't their official repository for their data. NASA does have publicly accessible websites where you can download the raw data in the form of text files containing the measured gray values of the pixels, see e.g. [here](https://data.nasa.gov/data).

Comment: @NormLDude Why do you keep saying "they removed the stars"?

Comment: I'll retract the 'they remove stars' comment. I'm really have no idea how this is achieved. But if anyone is interested, try different contrasts and lighting on the bottom right corner. There seems to be a lot of definition (3d)/depth to this 'anamoly'. The other circles surrounded by tiny circles are pretty interesting also.

Comment: They're just a combination of noise in the image and jpeg artefacts.  They might be interesting to you, but unless you're the type of person who hears hooves and expects to see zebra or really loves the fine artistry of the discrete cosine transform there is nothing of interest there.

Comment: @Count Iblis , I guess trying to verify any of this with my 'notebook' computer is futile. Albeit, a simple paragraph would have sufficed under the pic that was posted on Flickr "May not be exactly as shown here" or "The quality of this image is 44% of the original". Or something like that.

Comment: It's a lousy flikr post, not the best/only copy they have. Don't you butcher your own images to post them on websites for normal people to view in browsers?  That line *could* be a line of text before subsampling and compressing, and the position in the corner supports that.  Find the best quality res/format on NASA's site and don't worry about it.

Comment: @NormLDude *"There seems to be a lot of definition (3d)/depth to this 'anamoly'. The other circles surrounded by tiny circles are pretty interesting also."* that is all completely explained by my answer - the 3D shapes come from the primitive building blocks which are all based on [co]sine waves.

Comment: @NormLDude *a simple paragraph would have sufficed under the pic that was posted on Flickr "May not be exactly as shown here" or "The quality of this image is 44% of the original"* - the artifacts you're referring to are **completely invisible** until you perform a **huge** shadow boost, so why on Earth would they need to mention it? Should the same disclaimer be placed next to every JPEG image published anywhere in the web? Images NASA posts on Flickr are for PR purposes, not scientific analysis.

Comment: Why on Earth? Lol Matt. Funny. - @NormlDude. The compression is a well known effect on internet photos. This will sound a little harsh (it is not), you want to "find" things where there are none, and you did not "find" the original photos, the tiff uncompressed at least. You need to be more methodic on your experimentations. :0)

Comment: Here's an example of how they 'remove the stars'--Youtube search--NASA Fake Images of Earth - Smoking Gun [ Part 2 ]--[https://youtu.be/En6ot0bDr4Y]